# Giving a value to a function that requires the minibuffer

Tags: emacs

Suppose I have a function `(foo)` defined as `(defun foo () (read-from-minibuffer "What? "))`. I cannot change the definition, but I'd like to wrap it around a macro, or another function, so to avoid having to manually give any value.

Unfortunately the following solutions don't work, as `(exit-minibuffer)` is only called after leaving the minibuffer, so I was wondering if you know of something.

```
(defmacro return-an-empty-string (&rest code) `(progn ,@code (exit-minibuffer)))
(defun return-an-empty-string (function) (funcall function) (exit-minibuffer))
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you provide more details someone may be able to find a direct solution to your underlying problem.

Comment: my original problem was that the function `(slime-compile-and-load-file)` asked me every time to save the file and there was no variable to override this. I fix'd it with a variation of Sean's solution: `(defun slime-just-do-it () (interactive) (flet ((y-or-n-p (&rest ignore) t)) (slime-compile-and-load-file)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can temporarily make `read-from-minibuffer` into a do-nothing function:

```
(require 'cl)
(defmacro preempt-minibuffer (&rest body)
  `(flet ((read-from-minibuffer (&rest ignore)))
     ,@body))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to function source you can always make your own function that will do almost the same thing and substitute it for original function.

Suppose somewhere you have function `foo` in file `foo.el`

```
(defun foo ()
   ...)
```

Now you can add to your `.emacs`

```
(eval-after-load "foo"
                 '(progn
                   (defun foo+ ()
                     ...)
                   (fset 'foo 'foo+)))
```

and when `foo.el` will be loaded, if not already, your `foo+` will substitute original `foo`.